# Composer error in Eclipse plugin Symfony2

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin

I have installed symfony2 framework plugin in Eclipse 4.3. At the final step of setting a new symfony project it shows an error message: **Composer Error. Reason:could not open input file: app/console**. Please help to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you install the php-cli? sudo apt-get install php5-cli